# Why Pointer Type Cast Does not Work on Template Non-type Parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have the following code:

```
template <const char *p>
struct A{};

template <int i>
struct E{};

extern constexpr int i = 0;
constexpr float f = 0.f;
extern constexpr char c = 0;
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  A<&c> b; //works
  A<(const char *)(&i)> a; //Error: could not convert template argument ‘(const char*)(& i)’ to ‘const char*’
  E<(int)f> e; //works
  return 0;
}
```

why the line `A<(const char *)(&i)> a;` is wrong? I compiled it with g++-4.6.1 with -std=c++0x.

EDIT: As Charles suggested that `reinterpret_cast` is not permitted in a constant expression, I change the above code to the following:

```
struct Base{};
struct Derived : public Base {};

template <const Base *p>
struct A{};

extern constexpr Base base = {};
extern constexpr Derived derived = {};
A<&base> a; //works
A<(const Base*)&derived> b; //error: could not convert template argument ‘(const Base*)(& derived)’ to ‘const Base*’
```

Therefore, not only `reinterpret_cast` is not allowed. Using `A<static_cast<const base*>(&derived)` yields the same error.

To @BЈовић:

```
  A<(const Base*)(0)> b; // error: could not convert template argument ‘0u’ to ‘const Base*’
```

Comment: +1 interesting question. as i recall pointer cast is not permitted in "const expression". but i could be wrong, and if i'm right it only answers the immediate of why the compiler doesn't allow it, not why the standard is that way.

Comment: I believe that a `reinterpret_cast` is not permitted in a constant expression but I'm not sure about a C style cast that happens to resolve to a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Although the Standard goes through the trouble of defining the concept of _address constant expressions_ as a special kind of constant expressions, it does not make use of that concept in §14.3.2/1 where non-type template arguments are described: The template argument must either be integral or _the address of an object with static storage duration [...] **expressed as `& id-expression`** [...]_. The latter wording seems to rule out any kind of type casts.

Comment: 14.3.2/5 has `a valid template-argument for a non-type template parameter of pointer type. However, both (int*)0 and nullptr are valid template-arguments for a non-type template-parameter of type “pointer to int.”`, so this might be a compiler's bug. Although I am not sure.

Comment: I didn't know you could do `template<const char*>`. Is this new in C++11?

Comment: Could the problem be related to the fact that some pointer casts, at least for user-defined types, can result in a change to the actual value of the address? E.g. a `static_cast` from derived class to base class can cause the value of the pointer to change. Although the amount of the change should be predictable at compile time, perhaps there is a reason why this is very hard to combine with the evaluation of templates.

Comment: @tenfour It's in C++03, 14.3.2/1 "the address of an object or function with external linkage ..."

Comment: @jogojapan That's likely, but it would be reasonable to allow it for primitive types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for "the standard says so" answers, look in the comments.

The real question is *Why would this not be allowed?*

It makes a lot of sense to categorically refuse type conversions in template arguments, because what you are really interested in is the value of the template argument. **Type conversions however can become arbitrarily complicated and are not forced to be `constexpr`s. The standard (apparently) simply doesn't make an exception for built-in (primitive) types.**

Note that your `E<(int)f>` example is also refuted by `clang` with the reason:

> error: non-type template argument of type 'int' is not an integral constant expression

Why gcc allows this is dubious, but I'd assume it allows you to use `constexpr`s that you could explicitly declare. Note that this is *not* possible to sneak the address of `i` in the parameter list of `A`.

Comment: That makes sense. what does it mean by "this is not possible to sneak the address of i in the parameter list of A.", because `A<&c> b` actually compiles, which takes the address of `c`? Does it work with `clang`?

Comment: @DanqiWang: What I meant was, you cannot use an extra (e.g. global) variable to determine the address of `i` outside the argument list and then pass it as argument -- meaning we cannot cheat the compiler here. `A<&c> b;` compiles fine in `clang` -- as it should.

Comment: But why are certain type casts allowed for constant expressions of the _address_ type (§5.19/3, e.g. you can legally declare a separate expression `constexpr const char *pi = static_cast<const char *>(static_cast<const void *>(&i));`), but the same kind of type casts are explicitly ruled out when the constant expression is used as a template argument? Constant expressions (including address constant expressions) are designed so they can be evaluated at compile time (although they are not necessarily always implemented that way). Shouldn't that be good enough for a template argument?

Comment: @jogojapan: Good point. We'd have to ask the standardisation committee.